# R Studio getting the mean of vector of first 5 values, next 5 values etc

Tags: r, tapply

The code I am using is tapply(g,?, mean), the tapply function but I am confused about what to put in between g which is my vector, and the mean. The question asks to get the mean of each set of 5 values in a vector of size 100. So I will have 20 means altogether.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The second argument for `tapply` is the grouping - so you need to create something that indicates which values are grouped together, in your case you want every 5 values grouped, so something like  `1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,...` would work well. Perhaps if you play with `rep()` you can work out how to generate a vector like that.

Comment: HI Gregor Thomas, I've created a vector as you've mentioned with the following code:x<-1:20
g<- rep(x, each =5)  but I'm confused about what the next step should be

Comment: you can't use g as the first argument. I'm doing the same question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g<-c(1:100)
y<-rep(1:20, each=5)
tapply(g, y, mean)
```